# Coq: Trouble w/ a dependent pattern match

Tags: pattern-matching, coq

I wonder whether it's possible to pull off this dependent pattern match. As you see, I'm trying to map multiple values to `nul` (and instructing the output to have the required type w/ a `return` clause). Type `N` is a garbage collector, I'm simply trying to get rid of all the values after

```
| P, c => phy
| P, b => phy
| Ii, b => inf
```

(In this particular setting, using an `option` type seemed very unwieldy.) Note that if `Coercion` is impossible here, I'd be also happy w/ `Definition`

```
Inductive R := P | Ii | S | N.
Parameter rp:> R -> Prop.
Inductive X: Type := | c {z:P} :> X | b {z:P} {y:Ii} :> X.
Parameter (phy:P) (inf:Ii) (sen:S) (nul:N).

Check phy: id P.
Fail Coercion xi(y:R)(x:X): id y := match y, x with
| P, c => phy
| P, b => phy
| Ii, b => inf
| _, _ => match _ return N with _ => nul end end.
(* The term "nul" has type "rp N" while it is expected to have type "rp Ii". *)
```

Comment: Well that doesn't make sense, obviously there are many cases that will be typed differently from `N`, such as `Ii, c` which expects something of type `Ii` (by your return clause).

Comment: @ejgallego: You probably meant "by `id y`", not "by the return clause" (`return N`). Is there an alternative that might work? It may take more than one definition, but the last one should end w/ mappings to `phy`, `inf` and garbage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shorter solution w/ a definition returning a "match type":

```
Inductive R := P | Ii | S | N. Fail Check N: Type.
Parameter rp:> R -> Prop. Check N: Type.
Inductive X: Type := | c {z:P} :> X | b {z:P} {y:Ii} :> X.
Parameter (phy:P) (inf:Ii) (sen:S) (nul:N).

Definition xi (y:R) := match y return (match y with (P|Ii) => y | _ => N end) with
     | P => phy
     | Ii => inf
     | _ => nul end.

Eval hnf in xi S. (* = nul *)
```

Found the idea [here](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.MoreDep.html)

Answer (score 1):

You say "I'm simply trying to get rid of all the values after ...", and I am a bit concerned about having multiple default values with no distinguishing features, and I suspect that your code won't do what you think it will, but you can do this:

```
Inductive R := P | Ii | S | N.
Parameter rp:> R -> Prop.
Inductive X: Type := | c {z:P} :> X | b {z:P} {y:Ii} :> X.
Parameter (phy:P) (inf:Ii) (sen:S) (nul:N).

Check phy: id P.
Definition xi(y:R)(x:X): id y
  := match y, x with
     | P, c => phy
     | P, b => phy
     | Ii, b => inf
     | Ii, _ => inf
     | S, _ => sen
     | N, _ => nul
     end.
```

Note that you could just as well do this:

```
Definition xi(y:R)(x:X): id y
  := match y with
     | P => phy
     | Ii => inf
     | S => sen
     | N => nul
     end.
```

You can't make this a coercion because there's no way to infer `y` from `x`.

---

If what you care about are the values, rather than the types, you can use dependent types to get the return type you want in each case:

```
Inductive R := P | Ii | S | N.
Parameter rp:> R -> Prop.
Inductive X: Type := | c {z:P} :> X | b {z:P} {y:Ii} :> X.
Parameter (phy:P) (inf:Ii) (sen:S) (nul:N).

Check phy: id P.
Definition xi_type(y:R)(x:X)
  := match y, x return Type with
     | P, c
     | P, b
     | Ii, b
       => y
     | _, _
       => N
     end.
Definition xi(y:R)(x:X): xi_type y x
  := match y, x return xi_type y x with
     | P, c => phy
     | P, b => phy
     | Ii, b => inf
     | _, _ => nul
     end.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was attempting to map `S` to `N` (i.e. garbage), which (as @ejgallego mentioned) doesn't work w/ `xi`, so the latter is probably flawed anyway (I suspect that, minimally, it should not end on `id y`). That's why I asked (in my comment above) "Is there an alternative that might work? It may take more than one definition, but the last one should end w/ mappings to `phy`, `inf` and garbage". I want to map multiple values to garbage, which is also the reason I considered option type in my question (but found it too unwieldy)

Comment: It was not clear to me from your comment that you weren't attached to the `id y` return type.  I've updated my answer with a definition of `xi` with (basically) the body you give, but a different return type.

Comment: Gut! BTW, your definitions work as well w/out the return clauses